# import user modules that don't reconginze numpy after importing numpy

Tags: python, function, numpy, module

Let's say I created a script with function that I don't want to copy and past into the console every time I want to use it. I use numpy as np in the script.

`#define function in myscripts.py`

```
def myfunc (x, y):
  r1 = int(np.fix(np.random.uniform(x, y, 1)))
  return r1
```

So I save the above function in a file called myscripts.py and then run the following code.

`#import numpy and user-functions run user-function`

```
import numpy as np
from myscripts import myfunc
x=0
y=20
randu1=myfunc(x, y)
```

I get the following error.

`NameError: global name 'np' is not defined.`

What am I doing wrong? Is it how I import the function? Is it I need to make numpy global? I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: move the import statement in `myscripts.py`.

Comment: exactement @Jean-FrançoisFabre :)

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` needs to be important in the script where you defined the `myfunc` function which uses `numpy`

*myscripts.py*

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc (x, y):
  r1 = int(np.fix(np.random.uniform(x, y, 1)))
  return r1
```